# Display HTML if any item of cart got specific tag

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I want to implement two selectboxes in my shopify cart page if the cart contains an item with tag "test1"

my current code

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
  {% for products in item.products %}
      {% for tag in product.tags %}
          {% if tag contains 'test1' %}
            <select>....</select>
          {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That is, _one_ select box right there? every <select> ... </select> is one select box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below code. you are rendering unnecessary loops. item access product object directly and product can tags.

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
    {% if item.product.tags contains 'custom-tag' %}
         <h1> Yahoo </h1>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

O/P will like below Image

[image]

Comment: This would possibly show more than one version of the same select. Maybe add a {% break %} there?

Comment: all tags should and will be unique so control will go only one time in the if condition. This code checks every item in the cart for a particular tag if found it will render your HTML written in the IF condition.